# Git isn't merging my changes, although it says merge has been successful

Tags: git, github, merge

I got myself into a mess with Git merging, and have tried to undo it.  I think I have succeeded, and now I have the following:

master branch - looks as it did before the mess happened.  Everything committed and pushed to origin.
dev branch - looks as it did before the mess happened, and has the changes that I need to merge in.  Everything has been committed and pushed to origin.

So, I want to merge the dev branch into the master branch.  I can see (using git diff) that there are differences in several files.  I'm using VS Code, so I checkout the dev branch and create a pull request to merge into master.  The first time I did this, I got a message saying that the pull request couldn't be created, with the error "No commits between master and dev".

I made a dummy change and committed it, and tried another pull request.  This one worked, but only copied the dummy change to the master.

So, if I checkout the dev branch and do "git diff master" I get a list of changes across several files.  But if I try to merge the changes into master, I get the error about "No commits between master and dev".  What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: Here's the commit history (I've just numbered them consecutively for clarity):

1 (Master): Committed & pushed some changes, all fine at this point.

Created a branch from this commit, we'll call this branch "dev"

2 (Dev): Made changes, committed & pushed to dev.

3 (Dev): Made more changes, committed & pushed to dev.

4 (Merge): Merged dev into master

Realised that the work done for commit 3 wasn't needed. Reverted commit 4, then reverted commit 3.

5 (Attempted merge): tried to merge dev into master, but got the error message "No commits between master and dev"

Created new branch (dev2) from commit 3 (in case it needed to be a branch instead of a commit)

6 (Attempted merge): Tried to merge Dev2 into master, but again got the error "No commits between master and dev"

7 (Dev2): Made a "dummy change" (just changed some text), committed and pushed.

8 (Merge): Merged dev2 into master.  This worked, but only changed the text (the dummy change), not the rest of the files.

Comment: you'll have to better describe what you did to "undo it". Your message looks confused, try to put down facts: i run git revert, i run git merge etc...

Comment: You really need to describe the problem in more detail, *especially* what you did and what diffs you are seeing, and if the files you changed are ignored. Also "dev branch - [...]  has been committed and pushed to master." makes no sense at all. Maybe you mean it has been pushed upstream/to origin? Also, what happens if you do a simple git merge from the CLI? (instead of using VSCOde for making a PR)

Comment: Also, what "mess" did you make in the first place. describe how you got there, what you did to undo that etc.

Comment: Can you update your question with a view of the current history of your `master` and `dev` branches ? You can copy/paste the first lines of : `git log --graph --oneline master dev origin/master origin/dev` (you can edit the commit messages if you do not want to post them)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I got a message saying that the pull request couldn't be created, with the error "No commits between master and dev".
> I made a dummy change and committed it, and tried another pull request. This one worked, but only copied the dummy change to the master.

That only happens when dev started out behind master.  You had

```
*---D          dev
     \
      *---M    master
```

and sure, there's differences, but they're all on the master branch. Then you made your dummy change on dev, and merged that change.

Comment: See the way I drew my imaginary history?  Draw your actual history that way, then draw the history you want. Then we have something concrete to work with. To get a less-pretty but easier-to-produce rendition of your current actual history use `git log --graph --decorate --oneline master...dev`.

Comment: Thanks, I worked it out from your original comment - I had made a change to master which I hadn't pulled into dev.  Once I got dev up to date, it worked fine.  Thanks for your help!